# Custom properties in XSL

Tags: web-part, custom-web-part-property

Is it possible to pull the value of a property, from a web part into XSL?

I need to build something similar to the standard Summary Link Web Part, but would like to extend the default control with only a single property which will allow the editors of the site to supply a URL to a link, located in the footer-item of the SummaryLinkMainQuery.xsl.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Definitely passing webpart values to XSLT is possible for all classes which inherit from DataFormWebPart, and can be easily done through ParameterBinding:

```
<ParameterBinding Name="WPPropertyBinding" Location="WPProperty(Title)" />
```

Use your custom property name instead of `Title`.

If you're using a standard [SummaryLinkWebPart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.summarylinkwebpart.aspx) and you need only to fix XSL transformation, then all you have to do to achieve this, is to add the parameter binding string shown above to [ParameterBindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.dataformwebpart.parameterbindings.aspx) property of SummaryLinkWebPart.

Then, in XSLT, reference this parameter using following xsl code:

```
<xsl:param name="WPPropertyBinding" />
```

From this point, you will be able to use the parameter in XPath queries, for example:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$WPPropertyBinding" />
```

Read more about ParameterBindings on Stefan Stanev's blog, he has a really comprehensive article about it:

- http://stefan-stanev-sharepoint-blog.blogspot.com/2010/09/xsltlistviewwebpart-contentbyquerywebpa.html

Answer (score 3):

Watch out as SummaryLinkWebPart is a sealed class - you can't inherit it. Basically you'd have to build it from scratch.

Comment: just saw that as well. i wanted to get assurance that there is a way to call property values in xls, let's say "MyProperty {get; set;}", how would I call that in XSL? "<%=this.MyProperty%>" or something similar?

Comment: You could /try/ and adding to the list of xsl params that are at the top of the Main xsl.