# Basic XSLT: Using contentquerymain.xsl for several CQWP's

Tags: xslt, content-query-web-part

Is there anyway of specifying a `match` condition to determine which CQWP is being 'passed through' the XSLT in main.

Ultimately, I want to have a main.xslt file to serve several CQWP's but all must have a slightly different bit of markup.

In item style - I can evaluate the style like so:

```
<xsl:template name="News" match="Row[@Style='News']" mode="itemstyle">
       ...
      </xsl:template>
```

But if I attempt this in main.xslt it's never true:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate" />
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="OuterTemplate">
<div>
      <xsl:attribute name="class">
        <xsl:if test="Row[@Style='News']">
          TEST
        </xsl:if>  
      </xsl:attribute>
</div>
 </xsl:template>
```

I'm assuming that at a 'main' level I have no access to the Row @Style so is there anything else I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several options are available for this purpose:

### OOTB `WebPartId` parameter for CQWP

This parameter allows to identify instance of CQWP on page.

> **Pros**: No code solution
>   **Cons**: Not appropriate for deployment scenarios (web part id is generated during creation of CQWP instance)

For example:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$WebPartId = 'c7636893-cd8b-4d85-b8e7-f9659d149ce3'">
        <!-- Specific CQWP processing goes here -->
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <!-- Another CQWP processing goes here -->
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

---

### Extend (subclass) CQWP

```
public class ContentByQueryWebPartEx : ContentByQueryWebPart
{



    protected override void ModifyXsltArgumentList(ArgumentClassWrapper argList)
    {
        argList.AddParameter("cbq_instanceId", string.Empty, CBQInstanceId);
        base.ModifyXsltArgumentList(argList);
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Return the tool panes that configure this <see cref="T:Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart"/> object..
    /// </summary>
    [SharePointPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, ObjectModel = true)]
    public override ToolPart[] GetToolParts()
    {
        return new ToolPart[3]
                   {
                       new ContentByQueryToolPart(),
                       new WebPartToolPart(),
                       new CBQToolPart()   //Custom Tool Part 
                   };
    }


    #endregion



    [Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared),WebBrowsable(true)]
    public string CBQInstanceId { get; set; }




    #endregion
}
```

After referencing it XSLT

```
<xsl:param name="cbq_instanceId" />
```

it could be used in XPath queries

> **Pros**: Web part instance parameter could be specified during deployment process
>
> **Cons**: Implementation is required

### Extend (subclass) CQWP with parameter binding

```
public class ContentByQueryWebPartEx : ContentByQueryWebPart
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Return the tool panes that configure this <see cref="T:Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart"/> object..
        /// </summary>
        [SharePointPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, ObjectModel = true)]
        public override ToolPart[] GetToolParts()
        {
            return new ToolPart[3]
                       {
                           new ContentByQueryToolPart(),
                           new WebPartToolPart(),
                           new CBQToolPart()   //Custom Tool Part 
                       };
        }


        #endregion



        [Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared),WebBrowsable(true)]
        public string CBQInstanceId { get; set; }




        #endregion
    }
```

After specifying [ParameterBindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.dataformwebpart.parameterbindings.aspx) property in web part

```
<ParameterBinding Name="cbq_instanceId" Location="WPProperty(CBQInstanceId)" />
```

and referencing it XSLT

```
<xsl:param name="cbq_instanceId" />
```

it could be used in XPath queries:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$cbq_instanceId = 'ABC'">
        <!-- Specific CQWP processing goes here -->
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <!-- Another CQWP processing goes here -->
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

> **Pros**: Web part instance parameter could be specified during deployment process, no code solution
>
> **Cons**: Implementation for custom properties is required

Comment: How can we know WebPartId if we add this web part through UI and this property is dynamically assigned?

Comment: Good question, it seems in that case WebPartId could not be used.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can try to specify condition in the web part properties and use [this approach](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22044/custom-properties-in-xsl). Look at the answer of Andrey Markeev.